# Calling external python functions in file .py using ASP .NET MVC

Tags: python, asp.net-mvc

In ASP.NET MVC Application, I has an XML file. I also has an python function execute(xml_file) that take this xml file as an input in a test.py ( written in python3). This function will execute this xml file and return for me the list of results. And I want ASP .NET will take that result and display. How I can call that external module in ASP .NET MVC?

Answer (score 0):

You could start a new `Process` on C# code to run python and run your script.

You could start a new process calling the python. See the sample with comments:

```
ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();

// full path of python exe
start.FileName = "c:\\Python\\Python.exe";

string cmd = "C:\\scripts\\test.py";
string args = "";

// define the script with arguments (if you need them).
start.Arguments = string.Format("\"{0}\" \"{1}\"", cmd, args);

// Do not use OS shell
start.UseShellExecute = false;

// You do not need new window 
start.CreateNoWindow = true; 

// Any output, generated by application will be redirected back
start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

// Any error in standard output will be redirected back (for example exceptions)
start.RedirectStandardError = true; 

// start the process
using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
{
    using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
    {
        // Here are the exceptions from our Python script
        string stderr = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd(); 

        // Here is the result of StdOut(for example: print "test")
        string result = reader.ReadToEnd(); 

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: there are several functions in the script test.py, but I just want to call execute(xml_file), how I can do it?